# Functional testing using User model in a Laravel 8 package

Tags: laravel, functional-testing, laravel-package

I am coding a Laravel package, and I have written functional testing. For that, I need to seed users, using factories.

In my config, I have :

```
    'user' => [
        'table'       => 'users',
        'primary_key' => 'id',
        'foreign_key' => 'user_id',
        'model'       => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
```

But in my test package, App\Models\User is not defined, because it is only defined in main laravel project.

So, I tried to use `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` instead of `App\Models\User` in my tests, but I get a message :

```
InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory for [Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User].
```

Which I understand. But I cannot find a way to solve my issue a this point.

In my package's ServiceProvider, I have :

```
    $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../database/seeders' => $this->app->databasePath().'/seeders'], 'laravel-tournaments');
    $this->publishes([__DIR__.'/../database/factories' => $this->app->databasePath().'/factories'], 'laravel-tournaments');
    $this->publishes([__DIR__.'/../config/laravel-tournaments.php' => config_path('laravel-tournaments.php')], 'laravel-tournaments');
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the class is not defined" ? does it exist ? is the relative namespacing the issue, di you try `\App\Models\User::class` with a leading anti slash?

Comment: this class only exists when i use my package in a Laravel app. plugin assumes user Class exists in main project

Comment: if you are not using your package in a laravel app then what are you testing ? the vendor classes ?

Comment: I have not be clear. I use my package in laravel app, this is the purpose of all laravel packages. But when I run functional tests in my packages, I need to create users. But my package uses User model defined from laravel project. Package doesn't define his own User model, otherwise it would make a conflict between the two classes

Comment: I still dont understand where is the issue here. The one using your package will have to set in the configuration file the model to be tested. So the model needs to exist and implement factory. What is the issue again ?

Comment: Lol ^^ ! Yes you are right. Issue is that the User model is declared in Laravel project in `\App\Models\User`, but when testing the package in standalone, I there is no such class. So I tried to use a generic User class : `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` to generate my users, but it doesn't work. Also using a User::create() generate mass-assignement issue. When using `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`, I get the error : `InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory for [Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User].
`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer examinating [Laravel Permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/tree/main) package.

For functional testing, inside test folder, they put a TestModels/ folder with a copy of User class.

```
<?php

namespace Spatie\Permission\Tests\TestModels;

use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends UserWithoutHasRoles
{
    use HasRoles;
}
```

With trait `hasRoles` :

```
<?php

namespace Spatie\Permission\Tests\TestModels;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;

class UserWithoutHasRoles extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
    use Authenticatable;
    use Authorizable;

    protected $fillable = ['email'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'users';
}
```

All the models than depends on User should also be duplicated there